# How to allow only 1 radio button to be checked in html without giving them the same name?

Tags: html

[image]

Hello, as you can see I have this form for Employees to check in and out of their shifts, and the radio button is to determine wether the employee is checking in or out, How can I make it only 1 to be checked without giving them the same name? because giving the same name would ruin the POST request that handles the needed action.

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? You're expected to show your effort when posting a question here. And Why can't your radio buttons have the same name, as they should? How would it "ruin" the POST request?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change a CSS working and if your change it using a **JS** function then it will make the code slow , hard and even buggier

So try like this

```
<form action="/action_page.php">

  <input type="radio" id="check-in" name="GuestIsDoing" value="check-in">
  <label for="check-in">Check-in</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="check-out" name="GuestIsDoing" value="check-out">
  <label for="check-out">Check-out</label><br>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

CSS is made with reasons so it will not ruin the POST request that handles the needed action :

As it will be conveyed like this to server :
`GuestIsDoing=check-in/check-out`
that is
`input`value is used instead of `input` name

Answer (score -2):

```
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <p>Please select your favorite Web language:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="check-in" name="fav_language" value="1">
  <label for="check-in">check-in</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="check-out" name="fav_language" value="2">
  <label for="check-out">check-out</label><br>
</form>
```

Comment: **without giving them the same name**